# buildr and ranged maven transitive dependencies

Tags: maven, dependencies, buildr

Hoping some of you are already using buildr in your workflow. My question is, how do you resolve ranged maven dependencies that are transitive? Let me give you an example:

```
a-group:an-id:jar:a-version
```

say this depends on another dependency that is defined in ranges:

```
another-group:another-id:jar:[2.0.0,3.0.0)
```

It seems like buildr cannot resolve this. For instance I keep getting errors like this in my build:

```
RuntimeError : Failed to download com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:
[2.0.0,3.0.0), tried the following repositories: http://central.maven.org/maven2/
```

Answer (score 3):

Buildr does not resolve dependencies by design. The `transitive()` method is just a helper but not as sophisticated as Maven's Aether.

However, there are a few plugins that add that functionality to Buildr. The coolest approach is IMO taken by [LockJar](https://github.com/mguymon/lock_jar), which builds a Frankstein of Bundler and Maven and provides a nice abstraction to avoid the famous Maven Uncertainty Principle.

Comment: Hmm.. Didn't know about this. I'll check it out. In the meantime I gave up on the transitive thing and will be waiting an update from buildr folks.